Do hysteresis loop depends on the rate of change of $H$ during experimentation?
I am studying hysteresis loop, graph between Magnetic flux density $B$ and Magnetic field strength $H$. It follows that magnetic permeability of a medium changes while changing $H$. Magnetic permeability of a medium is defined as the ratio of $B$ and $H$.
Parallelly consider:
$\text{Speed of light in that medium}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon\mu}}$
where $\mu$ is magnetic permeability of a medium and $\epsilon$ is magnetic permittivity of a medium.
Cauchy's equation implies that speed of light in a medium depends on its wavelength in vacuum or we can say that frequency of light in vacuum. It implies that $\mu$ and $\epsilon$ of a medium are a function of the frequency of light (that is interacting with the medium) in vacuum.
Thus, it seems that the hysteresis loop for a particular setup should depend on how fast H is being changed. (Larger frequency can be thought of as faster changing electric and magnetic fields) Is it indeed the case?

This is true: the hysteresis loop depends very much on the rate of cycling. Just note that the "static permeability" defined as the ratio $B/H$ is really a meaningless quantity for a strongly nonlinear ferromagnetic material. The differential permeability $dB/dH$ that is the slope of the hysteresis is a more useful and meaningful quantity despite its dependence on the rate of cycling.
